# SPFX to check list contains field name

Tags: spfx-webparts

I have used the code from https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-list-form.

Based on the code above, I need add additional condition.

The code below I can get listId, and URL information. So I would like to pass another condition if the list contain field let say internal name = 'Category' otherwise pass null value. I thought I can do is `fieldsSchema[i].InternalName = 'Category' ?? null`.

```
let dt = await.listFormService.getFieldOptions(
    fieldSchema[i].LookupListId,
    this.props.webUrl,
    this.props.filterParam, //I need to check here if list contain field internal name = category
    this.props.filterValue
);
```

In this section I need add condition if list contain field with Internal name =' category and  I need to construct the code i.e

```
const endpoint = `${webUrl}/_api/Web/lists/getbyid('${listId}')/items?&$filter=filterParam eq 'Blue'&$top=5000`;
```

otherwise,

`const endpoint =` ${webUrl}/_api/Web/lists/getbyid('${listId}')/items?$top=5000`;`

```
public async getfieldOptions(listId: any, webUrl: string, filterParam: string, filterValue: string): Promise<any[]> {

        const endpoint = `${webUrl}/_api/Web/lists/getbyid('${listId}')/items?$top=5000`;


        try {
            let resp: SPHttpClientResponse = await this.spHttpClient.get(endpoint, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1);
            if (resp.ok) {
                let json = await resp.json();
                return json.value;
            }
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
        return [];

    }
```